# Python Pandas: deleting columns keeps index, unwanted extra index

Tags: python, pandas

So when I try to delete columns in my pandas dataframe either by using drop or del it keeps the index that I deleted for some reason, even if there aren't any value attributed to them. This is really messing with my for loops. I'm also using pickle I can as closely recreate the original problem as possible.

Here's my dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pickle

abc=b'\x80\x03cpandas.core.frame\nDataFrame\nq\x00)\x81q\x01}q\x02(X\x05\x00\x00\x00_dataq\x03cpandas.core.internals.managers\nBlockManager\nq\x04)\x81q\x05(]q\x06(cpandas.core.indexes.base\n_new_Index\nq\x07cpandas.core.indexes.multi\nMultiIndex\nq\x08}q\t(X\x06\x00\x00\x00levelsq\n]q\x0b(h\x07cpandas.core.indexes.base\nIndex\nq\x0c}q\r(X\x04\x00\x00\x00dataq\x0ecnumpy.core.multiarray\n_reconstruct\nq\x0fcnumpy\nndarray\nq\x10K\x00\x85q\x11C\x01bq\x12\x87q\x13Rq\x14(K\x01K\x04\x85q\x15cnumpy\ndtype\nq\x16X\x02\x00\x00\x00O8q\x17K\x00K\x01\x87q\x18Rq\x19(K\x03X\x01\x00\x00\x00|q\x1aNNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK?tq\x1bb\x89]q\x1c(X\x03\x00\x00\x00AAPq\x1dX\x03\x00\x00\x00CVXq\x1eX\x03\x00\x00\x00XOKq\x1fX\x04\x00\x00\x00DWDPq etq!bX\x04\x00\x00\x00nameq"Nu\x86q#Rq$h\x07h\x0c}q%(h\x0eh\x0fh\x10K\x00\x85q&h\x12\x87q\'Rq((K\x01K\x06\x85q)h\x19\x89]q*(X\x04\x00\x00\x00Openq+X\x04\x00\x00\x00Highq,X\x03\x00\x00\x00Lowq-X\x05\x00\x00\x00Closeq.X\t\x00\x00\x00Adj Closeq/X\x06\x00\x00\x00Volumeq0etq1bh"Nu\x86q2Rq3eX\x05\x00\x00\x00codesq4]q5(h\x0fcpandas.core.indexes.frozen\nFrozenNDArray\nq6K\x00\x85q7h\x12\x87q8Rq9(K\x01K\x18\x85q:h\x16X\x02\x00\x00\x00i1q;K\x00K\x01\x87q<Rq=(K\x03h\x1aNNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK\x00tq>b\x89C\x18\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03q?tq@bh\x0fh6K\x00\x85qAh\x12\x87qBRqC(K\x01K\x18\x85qDh=\x89C\x18\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05qEtqFbeX\t\x00\x00\x00sortorderqGNX\x05\x00\x00\x00namesqH]qI(NNeu\x86qJRqKcpandas.core.indexes.datetimes\n_new_DatetimeIndex\nqLcpandas.core.indexes.datetimes\nDatetimeIndex\nqM}qN(h\x0ecpandas.core.arrays.datetimes\nDatetimeArray\nqO)\x81qP}qQ(h\x03h\x0fh\x10K\x00\x85qRh\x12\x87qSRqT(K\x01K\x07\x85qUh\x16X\x02\x00\x00\x00M8qVK\x00K\x01\x87qWRqX(K\x04X\x01\x00\x00\x00<qYNNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK\x00}qZ(C\x02nsq[K\x01K\x01K\x01tq\\\x86q]tq^b\x89C8\x00\x08D+\xa5\xa4\xb0\x15\x000r\xb7v\xa5\xb0\x15\x00\xd0*\xe8\xbc\xa8\xb0\x15\x00p\xe3\x18\x03\xac\xb0\x15\x00\x98\x11\xa5\xd4\xac\xb0\x15\x00\xc0?1\xa6\xad\xb0\x15\x00\xe8m\xbdw\xae\xb0\x15q_tq`bX\x05\x00\x00\x00_freqqaNX\x06\x00\x00\x00_dtypeqbcpandas.core.dtypes.dtypes\nDatetimeTZDtype\nqc)\x81qd}qe(X\x04\x00\x00\x00unitqfX\x02\x00\x00\x00nsqgX\x02\x00\x00\x00tzqhcpytz\n_p\nqi(X\x10\x00\x00\x00America/New_YorkqjJ\xa0\xba\xff\xffK\x00X\x03\x00\x00\x00LMTqktqlRqmububh"X\x08\x00\x00\x00DatetimeqnhhhmX\x04\x00\x00\x00freqqoNu\x86qpRqqe]qr(h\x0fh\x10K\x00\x85qsh\x12\x87qtRqu(K\x01K\x17K\x07\x86qvh\x16X\x02\x00\x00\x00f8qwK\x00K\x01\x87qxRqy(K\x03hYNNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK\x00tqzb\x89B\x08\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\xd7\xa3p=\n\x8fc@)\\\x8f\xc2\xf5\x90c@\xf6(\\\x8f\xc2\xa5c@\\\x8f\xc2\xf5(\xb4c@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\xecQ\xb8\x1e\x85\x9bc@\x1f\x85\xebQ\xb8\xa6c@\xf6(\\\x8f\xc2\xb5c@\xd7\xa3p=\n\xc7c@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x14\xaeG\xe1z|c@\xecQ\xb8\x1e\x85\x8bc@R\xb8\x1e\x85\xeb\xa1c@\\\x8f\xc2\xf5(\xb4c@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\n\xd7\xa3p=\x92c@\x85\xebQ\xb8\x1e\xa5c@\xf6(\\\x8f\xc2\xb5c@{\x14\xaeG\xe1\xc2c@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\n\xd7\xa3p=\x92c@\x85\xebQ\xb8\x1e\xa5c@\xf6(\\\x8f\xc2\xb5c@{\x14\xaeG\xe1\xc2c@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x86\xd3@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00`\xd3@\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0\xd1\xf0@\x00\x00\x00\x00p\xab\xf9@\x9a\x99\x99\x99\x99y_@\xf6(\\\x8f\xc2u_@\xecQ\xb8\x1e\x85k_@\x14\xaeG\xe1zT_@\x14\xaeG\xe1zt_@\n\xd7\xa3p=z_@\xb8\x1e\x85\xebQx_@\x9a\x99\x99\x99\x99y_@\x9a\x99\x99\x99\x99y_@\xecQ\xb8\x1e\x85k_@\xd7\xa3p=\nw_@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80_@\\\x8f\xc2\xf5(|_@=\n\xd7\xa3p}_@\x9a\x99\x99\x99\x99y_@\xf6(\\\x8f\xc2u_@\xecQ\xb8\x1e\x85k_@33333S_@\xa4p=\n\xd7s_@q=\n\xd7\xa3p_@fffffv_@\x9a\x99\x99\x99\x99y_@\x9a\x99\x99\x99\x99y_@\xecQ\xb8\x1e\x85k_@\x14\xaeG\xe1zt_@fffffv_@H\xe1z\x14\xaew_@=\n\xd7\xa3p}_@\x9a\x99\x99\x99\x99y_@\x9a\x99\x99\x99\x99y_@\xecQ\xb8\x1e\x85k_@\x14\xaeG\xe1zt_@fffffv_@H\xe1z\x14\xaew_@=\n\xd7\xa3p}_@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7fq{tq|bh\x0fh\x10K\x00\x85q}h\x12\x87q~Rq\x7f(K\x01K\x01K\x07\x86q\x80h\x16X\x02\x00\x00\x00i8q\x81K\x00K\x01\x87q\x82Rq\x83(K\x03hYNNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK\x00tq\x84b\x89C8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc4\x83\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xda^\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Y\x13\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x85\x91\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00q\x85tq\x86be]q\x87(h\x07h\x08}q\x88(h\n]q\x89(h\x07h\x0c}q\x8a(h\x0eh\x0fh\x10K\x00\x85q\x8bh\x12\x87q\x8cRq\x8d(K\x01K\x04\x85q\x8eh\x19\x89]q\x8f(h\x1dh\x1eh\x1fh etq\x90bh"Nu\x86q\x91Rq\x92h\x07h\x0c}q\x93(h\x0eh\x0fh\x10K\x00\x85q\x94h\x12\x87q\x95Rq\x96(K\x01K\x06\x85q\x97h\x19\x89]q\x98(h+h,h-h.h/h0etq\x99bh"Nu\x86q\x9aRq\x9beh4]q\x9c(h\x0fh6K\x00\x85q\x9dh\x12\x87q\x9eRq\x9f(K\x01K\x17\x85q\xa0h=\x89C\x17\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03q\xa1tq\xa2bh\x0fh6K\x00\x85q\xa3h\x12\x87q\xa4Rq\xa5(K\x01K\x17\x85q\xa6h=\x89C\x17\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05q\xa7tq\xa8behGNhH]q\xa9(NNeu\x86q\xaaRq\xabh\x07h\x08}q\xac(h\n]q\xad(h\x07h\x0c}q\xae(h\x0eh\x0fh\x10K\x00\x85q\xafh\x12\x87q\xb0Rq\xb1(K\x01K\x04\x85q\xb2h\x19\x89]q\xb3(h\x1dh\x1eh\x1fh etq\xb4bh"Nu\x86q\xb5Rq\xb6h\x07h\x0c}q\xb7(h\x0eh\x0fh\x10K\x00\x85q\xb8h\x12\x87q\xb9Rq\xba(K\x01K\x06\x85q\xbbh\x19\x89]q\xbc(h+h,h-h.h/h0etq\xbdbh"Nu\x86q\xbeRq\xbfeh4]q\xc0(h\x0fh6K\x00\x85q\xc1h\x12\x87q\xc2Rq\xc3(K\x01K\x01\x85q\xc4h=\x89C\x01\x01q\xc5tq\xc6bh\x0fh6K\x00\x85q\xc7h\x12\x87q\xc8Rq\xc9(K\x01K\x01\x85q\xcah=\x89C\x01\x05q\xcbtq\xccbehGNhH]q\xcd(NNeu\x86q\xceRq\xcfe}q\xd0X\x06\x00\x00\x000.14.1q\xd1}q\xd2(X\x04\x00\x00\x00axesq\xd3h\x06X\x06\x00\x00\x00blocksq\xd4]q\xd5(}q\xd6(X\x06\x00\x00\x00valuesq\xd7huX\x08\x00\x00\x00mgr_locsq\xd8h\x0fh\x10K\x00\x85q\xd9h\x12\x87q\xdaRq\xdb(K\x01K\x17\x85q\xdch\x83\x89C\xb8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\r\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x11\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x15\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00q\xddtq\xdebu}q\xdf(h\xd7h\x7fh\xd8cbuiltins\nslice\nq\xe0K\x0bK\x0cK\x01\x87q\xe1Rq\xe2ueustq\xe3bX\x04\x00\x00\x00_typq\xe4X\t\x00\x00\x00dataframeq\xe5X\t\x00\x00\x00_metadataq\xe6]q\xe7ub.'
datas=pickle.loads(abc)
print(datas.to_string())
```

Output:

```
                              AAP                                                 CVX                                            XOK                                 DWDP                                
                             Open    High     Low   Close Adj Close    Volume    Open    High     Low   Close Adj Close  Volume Open High Low Close Adj Close Volume Open High Low Close Adj Close Volume
Datetime                                                                                                                                                                                                 
2019-07-12 07:15:00-04:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN       NaN  125.90  125.90  125.90  125.90    125.90       0  NaN  NaN NaN   NaN       NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN NaN   NaN       NaN    NaN
2019-07-12 07:30:00-04:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN       NaN  125.84  125.90  125.84  125.90    125.90       0  NaN  NaN NaN   NaN       NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN NaN   NaN       NaN    NaN
2019-07-12 08:30:00-04:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN       NaN  125.68  125.68  125.68  125.68    125.68       0  NaN  NaN NaN   NaN       NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN NaN   NaN       NaN    NaN
2019-07-12 09:30:00-04:00  156.47  156.86  155.89  156.57    156.57   19992.0  125.32  125.86  125.30  125.82    125.82  230340  NaN  NaN NaN   NaN       NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN NaN   NaN       NaN    NaN
2019-07-12 09:45:00-04:00  156.53  157.21  156.36  157.16    157.16   19840.0  125.82  126.00  125.81  125.85    125.85  155354  NaN  NaN NaN   NaN       NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN NaN   NaN       NaN    NaN
2019-07-12 10:00:00-04:00  157.18  157.68  157.06  157.68    157.68   68892.0  125.91  125.94  125.76  125.87    125.87  136025  NaN  NaN NaN   NaN       NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN NaN   NaN       NaN    NaN
2019-07-12 10:15:00-04:00  157.63  158.22  157.63  158.09    158.09  105143.0  125.88  125.96  125.85  125.96    125.96  102789  NaN  NaN NaN   NaN       NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN NaN   NaN       NaN    NaN
```

I try to delete the Nan parks, and it looks alright...

```
for i in datas.columns.levels[0]:     
     datas[i,'Indicator']=np.log(datas[i,'High']/6+
         datas[i,'Low']/6+
         datas[i,'Open']/3+
         datas[i,'Close']/3)
     del datas[i,'High']
     del datas[i,'Low']
     del datas[i,'Open']
     del datas[i,'Close']
     del datas[i,'Adj Close']
     datas[i,'Volume']=np.log(datas[i,'Volume']+1.0)
for i in datas.columns.levels[0]:  #Deletes all the depreciated symbols, yahoo finance guy didn't deal with his exceptions
    boolean=pd.isnull(datas[i]).all()
    if boolean[0] or boolean[1]:
        datas.drop(i,axis=1, inplace=True)
        print(i)
print(datas.to_string())
```

Output:
    XOK
    DWDP

```
                                 AAP        CVX       AAP       CVX
                              Volume     Volume Indicator Indicator
Datetime                                                           
2019-07-12 07:15:00-04:00        NaN   0.000000       NaN  4.835488
2019-07-12 07:30:00-04:00        NaN   0.000000       NaN  4.835250
2019-07-12 08:30:00-04:00        NaN   0.000000       NaN  4.833739
2019-07-12 09:30:00-04:00   9.903137  12.347316  5.052875  4.832890
2019-07-12 09:45:00-04:00   9.895506  11.953468  5.055131  4.835157
2019-07-12 10:00:00-04:00  11.140310  11.820601  5.058854  4.835303
2019-07-12 10:15:00-04:00  11.563086  11.540443  5.061846  4.835607
```

But it turns out those columns never left.

```
print(datas.columns)
```

Output:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['AAP', 'CVX', 'XOK', 'DWDP'], ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Adj Close', 'Volume', 'Indicator']],
           codes=[[0, 1, 0, 1], [5, 5, 6, 6]])
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:3812: PerformanceWarning: dropping on a non-lexsorted multi-index without a level parameter may impact performance.
  new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Good answers need good questions. Have a look at [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can edit your questions to make it easier to get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/2770

This seems to do the trick

```
datas.columns = datas.columns.remove_unused_levels()
datas.columns
```